# PHP Not working, Mac OS X El Capitan

Tags: php, macos, apache

having some issues getting PHP working and it's really frustrating.

I installed PHP from here: http://php-osx.liip.ch/

I have read and reviewed all of the tips/troubleshooting here: [PHP code is not being executed, instead code shows on the page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5121495/php-code-is-not-being-executed-i-can-see-it-on-source-code-of-page)

I have: uncommented the LoadModule for php

I have: added the command/line that makes files saved as .php be interpreted as php

I have: restarted apache, stopped and started apache

When I go to localhost/test.php I see the raw source code from my php file:

```
<!doctype html>
<html> 
<head>
<title> PHP Test </title>
</head>
<body>
<p>This is an HTML line. </p>
<?php echo “<p> This is a PHP line</p>”;
phpinfo();
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Any guidance appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What do your Apache Error logs show?

Comment: OS X comes with PHP preinstalled. There's no need for another installation.

Comment: OS X comes with an *old* version of PHP (5.5.27 in the case of El Capitan). There's always a need to install a newer version with OS X.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Uncomment the following too from httpd.conf

LoadModule rewrite_module libexec/apache2/mod_rewrite.so

Try that and with already uncomment Loadmodule for php, it should work
LoadModule php5_module libexec/apache2/libphp5.so

then restart apache

I have faced the similar issue and then this fixed it.

sudo apachectl restart

More detail can be found from url: http://coolestguidesontheplanet.com/get-apache-mysql-php-and-phpmyadmin-working-on-osx-10-11-el-capitan/

Comment: I have the same problem... That line is uncommented and so is the mod_rewrite.. I have verified that php does work on the command line. Any other ideas?

Comment: This is applicable on Mac Sierra too

Comment: For MacOS Mojave refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52609414/apache-not-working-after-macos-mojave-update/52640238#52640238

Answer (score 1):

I did

```
$ sudo mv /private/etc/apache2/other/+php-osx.conf   ~/Desktop
$ sudo apachectl start
```

and its working for me.

Comment: Nice THANK YOU SO MUCH! I've been struggling with this all week and these two terminal commands fixed it for me. Why does it work?