# MAC Os X (El Capitan) - enable PHP on local apache server

Tags: php, macos, apache

I configured local apache server on a mac. Files that are in the default folder (/Library/WebServer/Documents) under "localhost" domain are working fine.

I configured virtualhost typo3knjiga.test (/Library/WebServer/Documents/typo3knjiga) but php doesnt work, browser just outputs a row code.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Could you attach your host configuration?

Comment: <VirtualHost *:80>
        DocumentRoot "/Library/WebServer/Documents/typo3knjiga/"
        ServerName typo3knjiga.test

DirectoryIndex index.php

</VirtualHost>

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP Not working, Mac OS X El Capitan](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33108278/php-not-working-mac-os-x-el-capitan)

Comment: Unfortunately it doesnt work. 
I already had uncommented 
LoadModule rewrite_module libexec/apache2/mod_rewrite.so
LoadModule php5_module libexec/apache2/libphp5.so